# Arrow keys gallery navigation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add arrow key navigation to [this image gallery](http://www.pixelfreak.com/x/).

It should work similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/N5g8P/)

```
var chosen = "";
$(document).keydown(function (e) { // 38-up, 40-down
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        if (chosen === "") {
            chosen = 0;
        } else if ((chosen + 1) < $('li.t').length) {
            chosen++;
        }
        $('li.t').removeClass('selected');
        $('li.t:eq(' + chosen + ')').addClass('selected');
        $('li.t').click(this);
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        if (chosen === "") {
            chosen = 0;
        } else if (chosen > 0) {
            chosen--;
        }
        $('li.t').removeClass('selected');
        $('li.t:eq(' + chosen + ')').addClass('selected');
        $('li.t').click(this);
        return false;
    }
});
```

…but I want each arrow key press to work like a click since it should load a page in the iframe and at the same time perform another click action (moving the yellow frame to the newly selected thumbnail) just like it does now when clicking.

Also it would be great if going down with the arrow keys could force scrolling to keep the selected thumbnail in view.

…if I got this to work I imagine the next issue I'd run into would be that I would lose focus on the main page and the arrow key navigation whenever something is clicked within the iframe. This is a negligible issue but if there was a simple solution for it I would like to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please indent your code, it's much easier to read that way. :) And can you put together some form of a demo, that shows how you're dealing with images and how they're laid out?

Comment: Well the way I'm laying out the images is how it shows on the "this image gallery" link above, did you see it? not sure how else to make a demo. Sorry about how I leave the code, to me it's almost impossible to read anyway it's shown! :/

Answer (score 0):

Going with the jsfiddle you provided, you can simulate a user click with jquery's trigger() method.

```
$('li:eq('+whichIndex+') a').trigger("click");
```

This will cause the current code on your click event to run. This way you wont have to worry about having logic to keep track of clicks or key presses.

**Javascript**

```
var chosen = "";
$(document).keydown(function(e){ // 38-up, 40-down
    chosen = $('li.selected').index(); //grab the current selection
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
        if(chosen === "") {
            chosen = 0;
        } else if((chosen+1) < $('li').length) {
            chosen++; 
        }
        selectImage(chosen);
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        if(chosen === "") {
            chosen = 0;
        } else if(chosen > 0) {
            chosen--;            
        }
        selectImage(chosen);
        return false;
    }
});

function selectImage(whichIndex) {
    $('li:eq('+whichIndex+') a').trigger("click");
}
$("#selection a").click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('selected'); 
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

In this sample, the keydown event simply figures out which element should be the next "chosen". Once it's found, the selectImage() function is called which basically simulates a mouse click on the chosen element.

Clicking on the element (whether it's a user click, or a click called through jquery) will run the actual logic of de-selecting the old element and selecting the new element.

The fiddle with a working sample of this can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/DPHWZ/

Comment: Thanks JuanT… I was just trying to implement this and I noticed that when I added a real url to a list item it wouldn't load the url on key press but it would work when clicked. Clicks and key presses are not yet equals; any way to fix this?

Comment: That's strange, it should work. Theres no code that should be suppressing mouse clicks or key presses. Could you show me what you have so far?

Comment: You can see in the updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DPHWZ/1/) that the last two list items have urls that only load on the iframe below when clicked and not when selected with the arrow keys…